# Was or were at the start of question with multiple subjects?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which is correct?

> Were intent, action or dishonesty established during the interview?
>
> Was intent, action or dishonesty established during the interview?

Answer (score 1):

Were is used in a case where there is 'and' .
Correct: Were intent, action 'and' dishonesty established during the interview? 
Wrong: Were intent, action 'or' dishonesty established during the interview?

Was is used in a case where there is 'or' .
Correct: Was intent, action 'or' dishonesty established during the interview?
Wrong: Was intent, action 'and' dishonesty established during the interview?